# How to find the element corresponding to particular object using cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have just started with Cypress and it got my attention. However, when I try to be more specific with my testing I am finding it hard. The page which I am trying to automate has a form which looks like this:

```
<form>
   <div class="mb-3">
      <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-fullWidth">
         <label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated Mui-error Mui-error" data-shrink="false">Email address</label>
         <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline Mui-error Mui-error MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInput-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl"><input aria-invalid="true" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" type="email" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input" value=""></div>
         <p class="MuiFormHelperText-root Mui-error">Please enter a valid email address</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="mb-3">
      <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-fullWidth">
         <label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated Mui-error Mui-error" data-shrink="false">Password</label>
         <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline Mui-error Mui-error MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInput-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl"><input aria-invalid="true" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" type="password" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input" value=""></div>
         <p class="MuiFormHelperText-root Mui-error">Password should have minimum of 8 chars.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="mb-3">
      <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-fullWidth">
         <label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated" data-shrink="false">Confirm password</label>
         <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInput-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl"><input aria-invalid="false" name="password_confirm" placeholder="Confirm password" type="password" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input" value=""></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group pt-2 mb-4">By clicking the <strong>Create account</strong> button below you agree to our terms of service and privacy statement.</div>
   <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained mb-5 MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-containedSizeLarge MuiButton-sizeLarge" tabindex="0" type="submit"><span class="MuiButton-label">Create Account</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
</form>
```

Here I have error messages associated to 'email' and 'password' fields, both elements in a

under respective 's.
I can validate the error messages by using below statement easily:

```
cy.get('p').contains('Please enter a valid email address')
and
cy.get('p').contains('Password should have minimum of 8 chars')
```

But what I want to do is, get the  element and find the child

of my div element and then get the text of my

element.
Why I want to do this is to make sure that the error message that I am trying to validate actually corresponds to my test element.

How can I achieve it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by traversing the DOM from your helper text:

```js
cy.get("p")
  .contains("Please enter a valid email address")
  .then(($el) => {
    expect($el.siblings("label").text()).to.eq("Email address");
  });

cy.get("p")
  .contains("Password should have minimum of 8 chars")
  .then(($el) => {
    expect($el.siblings("label").text()).to.eq("Password");
  });
```